# How to deploy React app in with firebase?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, firebase

Iam Trying to deploy my react and express js web application with firebase. But after spending a lot of time I was unable to deploy my site through firebase.

Answer (score 1):

***create-react-app*** have clear doc
[react firebase deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment#firebase)

***express.js*** is back-end application can use in [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started). or search simlar other [milesweb](https://www.milesweb.in/hosting/nodejs-hosting),[ionos](https://www.ionos.com/hosting/cheap-web-hosting)